# Where does location data come from in an ad call on my mobile app?

Tags: mobile, gps, location, ads

I have a mobile app that uses GPS for location. I have ads on my app that accesses a mobile exchange. When there is a bid request and an ad call occurs, does the location data come from my app or from the user's default API on their mobile device? Alternatively, if my app used user registration for location, would that data be used in the ad call request?

Really appreciate any insight here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain it comes from the users device. I know with google ads they use it based on user location, depending on device settings. Here's a snippet from the google adsense site and I'd assume others are like it (https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/2453995?hl=en):

**IP address:
Location is typically based on the Internet Protocol (IP) address, which is a unique number assigned by Internet Service Providers to each computer connected to the Internet.
If a mobile device is connected to a Wi-Fi network, we may detect the mobile device's IP address to determine physical location. If the mobile device is connected to a mobile carrier's proxy server, we may use the carrier IP to determine the device's location.
Device location:
If users have enabled precise location sharing on a mobile device, we can detect the device location, and use on the search network, from one of the following sources based on availability:
GPS: Accuracy varies depending on GPS signal and connection.
Wi-Fi: Accuracy should be similar to the access range of a typical Wi-Fi router.
Google's cell ID (cell tower) location database: Used in the absence of Wi-Fi or GPS. Accuracy is dependent on how many cell towers are located within an area and available data, and some devices don't support cell ID location.**

Comment: I wonder if that's specific to AdWords or if it's different w/ ad inventory available across the open exchange. The following post leads me to believe there are instances where location data comes from the app instead of the device (I think this instance is with programmatic ad buying?): "location data in an ad request wasn’t always accurate or true. The reason for that is publishers have many different ways of pulling location data. They can pull it straight off of the device’s GPS..." adexchanger.com/mobile/thinknear-ceo-talks-hyperlocal-advertising-and-the-importance-of-good-location-data/